# correct way to filter execve environment

Tags: c, environment-variables, ld-preload, execve

I'm trying to write a `LD_PRELOAD`able library that prevents processes from removing itself from this variable (to make sure children inherit it).
So far I sucessfully wrapped `putenv`,`setenv` and `clearenv`, but `execve` gives me issues.

My code so far:

```
int (*real_execve)(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]){
  real_execve = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"execve");
  char *path = getenv("LD_PRELOAD");
  fprintf(stderr, "INTERCEPTED execve, env:\n");
  int i;
  for(i=0;envp[i]!=NULL;i++);
  char *nenvp[i+1];
  nenvp[i]=NULL;
  for(i=0;envp[i]!=NULL;i++){
    char *string = envp[i];
    char *buf = malloc((strlen(string)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buf,string);
    char *name = strtok(buf,"=");
    char *value = strtok(NULL,"=");
    if(0==strcmp(name,"LD_PRELOAD")){
      fprintf(stderr,"  FIXING '%s'\n",string);
      char * nstring = malloc((strlen(name)+strlen(path)+strlen(value)+3)*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(nstring,name);
      strcat(nstring,"=");
      strcat(nstring,path);
      strcat(nstring,":");
      strcat(nstring,value);
      nenvp[i]=nstring;
      fprintf(stderr,"    TO  '%s'\n",nenvp[i]);
      free(string);
    }else{
      nenvp[i]=envp[i];
      fprintf(stderr,"  LEFT  '%s'\n",nenvp[i]);
    }
    free(buf);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "  CALLING %s\n", filename);
  return real_execve(filename,argv,nenvp);
}
```

I'm encountering 2 issues:

- it logs things like:

  ```
  FIXING 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1'
    TO  'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1:/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1'
  ```

  instead of the expected prepending of the path to self, so I guess I somehow messed up the strtok.
- I get a lot of errors like those:

  `Error in 'sh': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff3888af4a`

  which to me sounds like I'm freeing too much probably, but I can't find the culprit.

I hope this doesn't sound too much like a "hey fix this for me" post but I'm kinda hitting a wall here and any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to (re-)read the docs for `strtok`. If you call it twice with the same string and delimiter, you'll get the same result. The second and subsequent calls must have NULL as their first argument.

Comment: totally glanced over that apparently. thank you very much, i'll fix that and then either edit my question to reflect the 2nd issue or if it goes away close it (if you rephrase your comment as an answer i'll gladly upvote/accept it).

Comment: ok after applying that fix it now duplicates the value in `value` instead of prepending the `path` to it. also still getting the `munmap_chunk` error

Comment: `strcpy(nstring,name);
      strcat(nstring,"=");
      strcat(nstring,path);
      strcat(nstring,":");
      strcat(nstring,value);` Please take a look at `sprintf()` and `snprintf()`

Comment: Probly unrelated but keep in mind that `execve` is supposed to be async signal-safe so you can't really call non-async-safe functions from it (`malloc`, `strtok`, etc.). For list of legal functions see [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: @yugr good to know. `strtok_r` would be signal safe, but i can't seem to find a `malloc` alternative, does that mean i need a giant statically allocated buffer and just hope i don't run out of space?

Comment: @nonchip That's what I normally do as `alloca` and `mmap` are not guaranteed to be async-safe on all Unix flavors ([signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this straight forward:

- Create a *new* pointer array with the size necessary to hold the new env/ var/s
- `strdup()` all elements you need from the old to the new array.
- Add new stuff as necessary.
- Make sure the last pointer in the array is `NULL`.
- Pass the new pointer array to the original `execve()`.

Do *not* modify or even (try to) `free()` entries of the old environment.

Comment: that's essentially what's happening now (just without the strdup, reusing the old elements currently, seems to work just fine). the only thing i don't get is why it's still not doing its job right, but i hope i'll figure that out at some point. if you're interested you can take a look at https://github.com/nonchip/steam_workaround_fsoverflow

Comment: @nonchip: The important thing is to leave to "old" environment alone. Although you most likely do not need to `strdup()`, yes. But you definitely may not free or modify "old" stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume that an individual string in `envp` was allocated with `malloc` so `free(string)` could be Undefined Behaviour. It is virtually impossible to call `exec*` with a completely empty heap and the entire image will be replaced anyway, so it's not worth worrying about.

Your second `strtok` call should supply `NULL` as its first argument. See `man strtok` for an explanation and examples.

Comment: removing the `free(string)` got rid of the `munmap_chunk` problem, replacing my `strtok` call by a `char* sep = strchr(buf,"="); *buf='\0'; name=buf; value=sep+1;` (to make sure it doesn't split at subsequent `=` chars, and manually split the string) makes it duplicate the `value` (with the `:` in between) now, instead of concatenating the `path` and `value`. almost as if i'm overwriting the path somehow but i don't do that. is `getenv` confused maybe? even `strcpy`ing the path in the beginning doesn't help

Comment: Are you sure you're getting "your" `LD_PRELOAD`? Maybe it was already `setenv`ed. Maybe your `setenv` intercept has UB... I'd use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: apparently it got setenv'd somehow even though I thought I intercepted that (maybe because the fork caused my interception to not work anymore?). moving the `getenv` to a `__attribute__((constructor))` fixed it, even though apparently my library still doesn't get loaded everywhere.